# Как реализовать морской бой? [Canvas NJs]

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как реализовать морской бой, генерация пикчи; Библиотека Canvas, ЯП: Node Js.

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте файлик index.html
2. Заверстайте простенькую страничку, содержащюю <canvas>
3. Напишите реализацию поля, кораблей и выстрелов
4. Напишите ИИ и\или напишите код, отвечающий за взаимодействие с пользователем
5. PROFIT

Comment: мне для бота нужно

Comment: @Voxel значит, пункт 4 для вас сокращается до "Напишите ИИ"